# Why can't I successfully to fetch url from form and thus attribute it to the source(src) of images?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've having an issue I shouldn't be having with my Node/Express code(s). I can't for the life of me get the image source (src) attribute to work, hence the images added from a form aren't being displayed. It just displays as unknown. I have no idea where I'm going wrong, and have gone through the whole code(s) multiple times, but nothing seems out of place.

The JS code is as follows:

```
var express    = require("express"),
    app        = express(),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    mongoose   = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/yelpcamp");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

//Camp Schema
var campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    image: String
});

var Campground = mongoose.model("Campground", campgroundSchema);

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("landing");
});

app.get("/campgrounds", function(req, res){
    Campground.find({}, function(err, sites) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            res.render("campgrounds", {
                campgrounds:sites
            });
        }
    });
});

app.post("/campgrounds", function(req, res){
    //Fetching data from form
    var name = req.body.campName;
    var url = req.body.imageUrl;
    var newCamp = {
        name: name, 
        image: url
    };
    //New Campground and Save to DB
    Campground.create(newCamp, function(err, campground) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            //Redirect to Camp Page
            console.log(campground);
            res.redirect("/campgrounds");
        }
    });
});

app.get("/campgrounds/new", function(req, res){
    res.render("new");
});

app.listen(4500, function(){
   console.log("Yelp Camp Server Started!!!"); 
});
```

The following are the relevant EJS codes:

**Form EJS**

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="/campgrounds" method="POST">
        <label for="campName">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="campName" name="campName" placeholder="Add Campground Name">
        <label for="campImage">Image</label>
        <input type="url" id="campImage" name="imageUrl" placeholder="Add Image Url">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Campground">
    </form>
    <a href="/campgrounds">Go Back</a>
</div>
```

**Add Image EJS**

```
<div class="container">     
    <h1 style="margin-top: 8%;">Campgrounds Presentation</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <% campgrounds.forEach(function(campground) { %>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="<%= campground.image %>">
                <h3 class=text-center><%= campground.name %></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% }); %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on 'unknown'. What does the generated <img ... look like?

Comment: Rather than the returned html code being <img src="url" >, I get <img src(unknown)>.

Comment: Did you try logging the output of 'Campground.find' method? Are image urls comming in its output?

Comment: Actually, I just got it to work. For some reason, changing the the input type (in the form EJS) from url to text did the trick. No idea why but it's all good. Cheers!